# Dynamic Cell Height in MvvmCross

Tags: ios, dynamic, xamarin, height, mvvmcross

I want to override the GetHeightForRow method, so my scroll works perfectly when scrolling to a specific cell (row).

I found this example [here](https://github.com/kentcb/TableViewCellWithAutoLayout_dotNET) that is working perfectly. Because of this part of the code:

```
 public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (this.offscreenCell == null)
        {
            this.offscreenCell = new ItemCell();
        }

        var cell = this.offscreenCell;

        cell.UpdateFonts();
        var item = this.model.Items[indexPath.Row];
        cell.Title = item.Title;
        cell.Body = item.Body;

        cell.SetNeedsUpdateConstraints();
        cell.UpdateConstraintsIfNeeded();

        cell.Bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0, this.TableView.Bounds.Width, this.TableView.Bounds.Height);

        cell.SetNeedsLayout();
        cell.LayoutIfNeeded();

        var height = cell.ContentView.SystemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UIView.UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).Height;
        height += 1;

        return height;
    }
```

Tried to translate it to my MvvmCross project, for something like:

```
public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (this.offscreenCell == null)
        {
            this.offscreenCell = new ItemCell();
        }

        var cell = this.offscreenCell;
        cell.DataContext = this.model.Items[indexPath.Row];

        cell.SetNeedsUpdateConstraints();
        cell.UpdateConstraintsIfNeeded();

        cell.Bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0, this.TableView.Bounds.Width, this.TableView.Bounds.Height);

        cell.SetNeedsLayout();
        cell.LayoutIfNeeded();

        var height = cell.ContentView.SystemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UIView.UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).Height;
        height += 1;

        return height;
    }
```

But it is always returning 36.5 no matters what. Any clue of how to make it?

Thanks in regards,

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck with a UICollectionView instead of a UITableView. Overall, they're more flexible than table views.

If you give it a try, you'll find it's quite easy to do custom heights for individual items (collection views have items instead of cells).

First, you need create a custom UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout:

```
public class ThingDelegateFlowLayout : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    List<Thing> Things;

    public ThingDelegateFlowLayout(List<Thing> things)
    {
        Things = things;
    }

    // this is the override that allows you to dynamically size UICollectionView items
    public override SizeF GetSizeForItem (UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return new SizeF(
            width: UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, // Set the width to whatever you want. In this case, it's the screen width.
            height: Things[indexPath.Row].Height // Set the item height
        );
    }
}
```

Then in your view controller do something like the following. Note the important line...

`thingCollectionView.Delegate = new ThingDelegateFlowLayout(Things);`

...near the bottom, where you're assigning the the custom UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout to the UICollectionView:

```
public class ThingViewController : UIViewController
{
    private List<Thing> Things;

    public ThingViewController()
    {
        Things = GetThings();
    }

    // gets a list of sweet hair dos
    private List<Thing> GetThings()
    {
        // do something here to get a sweet list of hair dos
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout () 
        {
            HeaderReferenceSize = new SizeF(0, 0), // no header
            FooterReferenceSize = new SizeF(0, 0), // no footer
            SectionInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, 0, 0), // no section inset
            ItemSize = new SizeF(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, 100f), // set each item to the full width of the screen and 100 pixels tall
            ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical, // set the collection to scroll vertically
            MinimumInteritemSpacing = 0, // no item spacing
            MinimumLineSpacing = 0, // no line spacing
        };

        var thingCollectionViewController = new UICollectionViewController(layout);
        var thingCollectionView = new UICollectionView(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size);

        thingCollectionViewController.CollectionView.Frame = thingCollectionView.Frame;
        thingCollectionView = thingCollectionViewController.CollectionView;
        thingCollectionView.Delegate = new ThingDelegateFlowLayout(Things);
        thingCollectionView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear; // or whatever
        thingCollectionView.BackgroundView = new UIView () 
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear // or whatever
        };

        View.AddSubview (thingCollectionView);
    }
}
```

I don't know exactly how to do it with a UITableView. I've basically just stopped using table views, because I much more prefer UICollectionViews.

Comment: it would result in the same problem i'm facing. if i want a view controller cell with dynamic height, i would have to calculate it in thingdelegateflowlayout.getsizeforitem... the problem is how to calculate it with mvxtableviewcell ...